# Optimising ifTrue:ifFalse: in Smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk

The Smalltalk Blue Book says that the compiler optimises `ifTrue:ifFalse:` and friends using special opcodes, so as to avoid having to create closures and do dynamic dispatch to the actual Boolean object.

If I've understood this correctly, then:

```
o ifTrue: [ ^ 'yes' ] ifElse: [ ^ 'no' ]
```

...becomes something like:

```
    push o
    jump_if_false 1
    return 'yes'
    jump 2
1:
    return 'no'
2:
```

(And I checked, and GNU Smalltalk does exactly this.)

This would work fine if `o` is a `Boolean`, but I don't understand what would happen if it isn't. After all, the *compiler* doesn't know what type `o` is. It can't guarantee it's a Boolean. It doesn't even know whether the `ifTrue:ifFalse:` method has the traditional semantics.

For example:

```
Fnord ifTrue: tb ifFalse: fb
    "muhahaha"
    tb value: self.
    fb value: self and: 9.
    ^ 7
```

For this implementation to work, the true and false blocks *must* be closures, taking one and two parameters respectively. So how does the compiler know to generate the closures? Or is the compiler allowed to break in this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the bytecodes (in the dialect I'm using)

```
1  frameless prolog
2  load R with instance o       ; o is an ivar in my code
4  test jump false 13 
7  load R with literal 'yes'
9  return
10 jump 16
13 load R with literal 'no'
15 return
16 return self
```

And here is the nativized code (simplified):

```
    cmp eax, false       ; test jump false
    jz @2
    cmp eax, true
    jz @1
    call mustBeBoolean   ; <--- here!
@1: mov eax, 'true'
    ret
    jmp @3               ; jump
@2: mov eax, 'no'
    ret
@3: move eax, esi
    ret
```

As you can see, it is the JIT Compiler (a.k.a. nativizer) who checks whether the receiver of `#ifTrue:ifFalse:` is a Boolean or not. More precisely, the nativization of the `test jump false` bytecode emits code that will send the `mustBeBoolean` notification if the receiver isn't a Boolean.

**EDIT**

With respect to your second question, the implementation of `#ifTrue:ifFalse:` in another class would not work if the sender inlines (explicitly) the block arguments as in:

```
receiver ifTrue: ['yes'] ifFalse: ['no']
```

This code will fail with `#mustBeBoolean` if `receiver` is an instance of `Fnord` (even though `receiver` understands `#ifTrue:ifFalse:`.) The reason is that, in this case, the compiler will optimize `#ifTrue:ifFalse:` as we saw above instead of sending it as a regular message.

However, the expressions

```
receiver ifTrue: [:a | <whatever>] ifFalse: [:a :b | <your code>]
```

and

```
fa := [:a | <whatever>].
fb := [:a :b | <yourcode>].
receiver ifTrue: fa ifFalse: fb
```

will not be optimized, meaning that `#ifTrue:ifFalse:` will be sent.

Comment: what works in Squeak is to just send #yourself to one of the blocks to defeat optimization... self testSomething ifTrue: [self doSomething] yourself ifFalse: [self doAnother]. It remains to see what gst compiler does in this case...

Comment: It suddenly occurs to me that if `o` *isn't* a `Boolean`, then `mustBeBoolean` can do the equivalent of `o ifTrue: [true] ifFalse: [false]` to convert it into a primitive Boolean; at which point the optimised code will just work.

Comment: Also, experimentation shows that gst won't optimise the second case. And, yes, calling `yourself` on the block defeats optimisation too. That all makes sense, thanks.

Comment: (What's really interesting is that gst won't optimise `o ifTrue: [|j| j := 1. j] ifFalse: [2]`...)

Comment: @aka.nice That makes sense. The parser will tell that `[<code>] yourself` is not a `BlockNode` but a `MessageNode`, and the optimization only happens when the arguments are BlockNodes with no args.

Comment: @DavidGiven I see no reason for preventing the optimization in the presence of block temporaries.

Comment: Me neither. I suspect it's a shortcut so they don't have to create block temporaries in the outer block and have to worry about name collisions. It does seem rather an oversight, though.